# Javascript replace a combination of back and forward slash with a single forward slash

Tags: javascript, replace, escaping

in Javascript, I am having some trouble replacing '/' with '/' in a string. I tried this

```
string.replaceAll("\\/","/"));
```

What's wrong with this ? I am escaping the escape character i.e. the backslash.

Please advise. Thanks
Edit: I have an escaped URL such as http://www.gogobeans.com. I need to change this to http://www.gogobeans.com

Comment: Can you paste the whole line?

Comment: And what is the trouble you have? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never heard of `replaceAll` method in pure javascript, try `replace` with a regex:

```
 string.replace(/\\\//g, "/");
```

I've escaped the escape character with `\\` then escaped the scope character `/`, it should work.

JSFiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/s4vvb/1/)**

Comment: You are missing the global modifier (if you want to replace all occurrences). And if that is the only problem, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Well then...I'm writing from my phone, everything is a bit slow ;)

Comment: No problem. :) Added a fiddle example.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. I, for some stupid reason assumed that there is a replaceAll function in JS. Thanks everyone