# String replace javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string = Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string-javascript)
>   [How to replace all points in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-points-in-a-string-in-javascript)

I have a string `2012/04/13`. I need to replace the `/` with a `-`. How can i do this ?

```
var dateV = '2012/04/13';
dateV= dateV.replace('/','-');
```

It only replaces the first `/` and not all `/` in the string (`2012-04/13`). What should i do to correct this ?

Comment: Look at the `g` flag for regexes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10507770/1331430 (good reference as well), but I'm voting to close with the first as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a global regex replace using the global regex option. This should work for you:

```js
var dateV = '2012/04/13';
var regex = new RegExp("/", "g"); // "g" - global option
dateV = dateV.replace(regex, "-");
console.log(dateV);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dateV= dateV.replace(/\//g,'-');
```